# How can I monitor background radiation from the universe with a reasonable accuracy?

Tags: radiation, big-bang

Physics newbie here investigating for a potential art project.

As I understand, radio and TV static contain approximately 1%, is there a way or a device I can buy/build that will increase the amount I can gather?

Would I need to get something up high, such as a high-altitude balloon, or is there perhaps some other way I can increase that percent.

As I said, it will be for a musical/art project so accuracy can vary, however more than 1% would be desirable.

Comment: Radiation is a very wide spectrum. A digital camera will monitor "background radiation" in the visible spectrum. You'd need more specialized tools to see background radiation in other parts of the EM spectrum. It also depends on whether you're looking for 1D, 2D, or 3D representation (you could even do 4D if you want to record a 3D thing over time). If you're talking about the [cosmic microsave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), I don't think you can do that with amateur instruments. Describing your project might help narrow the question down.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the project is a musical art project that takes sources from nature, slowly moving up from crystals, to microbes, to insects, to humans, to the stock exchange... and so on. Each category has some sort of moving source that participants can assign to various parameters of ambient music... for the very final phase, I was hoping some kind of data related to the universe, would be a great way to end it... even if it's just noise, it would actually be a good finale. It has to be live that's the catch, a friend suggested I check out Quasar feeds if there are any.

Comment: If its an art/sensory  based experience you are after , why not take the actual WMAP based data, the best quality source, and turn it into a sound? They do pretty much the same thing with whale songs, which are way below our human senses, so the frequency is shifted up.  I am no artist, but I know what I hate...and I wouldn't hate that.......best of luck with it anyway

Comment: @MichaelS - I know 'amateurs' with much better equipment than Penzias and Wilson had in 1964 (particularly low noise amplifiers in the right frequency regime, but generally all the electronics). In the last 50 years there have been a few improvements (!), so replicating the original experiment really isn't that hard for any experimental physicist in their spare time.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you're looking for a live feed from some type of extraterrestrial signal that could be converted into an audible sound. I don't know what kind of technical expertise you have in actually converting, but I'll talk about some resources you could use. I'm also assuming this project is probably during the day time.

This isn't really a nice answer. I simply don't know of any good way to do this. However, I'm hoping the information here will give you a better understanding of what kind of data we *can* get, which will hopefully allow you to find something that works with your project.

The hardest part is probably finding real-time data. Very few high-speed data sources are going to be available in real-time. Getting data that's hours to days old then playing it on a loop or something is much more feasible.

**Radiation**

The most prevalent source of extraterrestrial signals is EM radiation. This includes radio waves, microwaves, infrared, visible light, ultraviolet, x-rays and gamma rays. Each of these is typically subdivided further for convenience, but they're really all the same thing with different energy levels per photon.

By far, the largest source of radiation hitting the planet comes from our own Sun, with about 1 kilowatt of energy in the infrared, visible, and ultraviolet parts of the spectrum, centered in the visible area. So you could just stick a photosensor outside and detect variations in sunlight.

Anything higher than ultraviolet is blocked by the atmosphere (which is a good thing, since [high-energy radiation is bad for your health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation#Health_effects)). So you'd need to get that data from satellites.

Microwaves sources are generally going to be drowned out by the sunlight, but at some point you get to long enough wavelengths you can probably see past the sun. Still, the longer the wavelength, the bigger of a satellite dish you need.

You could potentially get background microwave or radio wave radiation by plugging into an analog TV antenna. The only problem with this is that you're mostly just seeing stray signals from terrestrial sources. After all, those antennas were designed to pick up terrestrial radio waves.

For more space-based radio waves, you start needing [very large antenna arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Large_Millimeter_Array) (of note, that particular array is for taking radio *photographs*, which means 2D data, not just 1D data like you'd use for sound, and is therefore a lot more complex than you'd need).

Alternately, you'll need to get satellite data, but I'm having a hard time finding anything remotely real-time in this regard. There's a site with data from the [LAT](http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/access/lat/), or [Large Area Telescope](http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/). But I'm not exactly sure how to access the data, and I don't think it's in real time. But it does gamma ray detection, which is pretty awesome.

**Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation**

The [CMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) is light from a "surface" that existed about 380 thousand years after the Big Bang. It's basically the first time in history that solid matter existed, and is the closest time to the Big Bang we can actually see. It's a pretty cool thing to study, but doesn't really change much over time. So you probably don't want to use it for a real-time music signal.

It's about 2.72548 Kelvin, which translates to a wavelength of [1 mm](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/wien.html#c3) (which, as the name suggests, is in the microwave band). From what I can tell, those microwaves should be visible with a ground-based antenna, but I think they're pretty dim. I notice that most, if not all of the [CMB experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cosmic_microwave_background_experiments) are done using very expensive equipment.

**Sky Map**

Not real time, and probably not relevant. But while looking for other stuff in this answer, I found [Sky Map](http://www.sky-map.org/), which is a Google Maps-esque web application, allowing you to see the universe stitched together from tons of images from observatories world wide.

You could take part of the sky, say the [Andromeda Galaxy](http://www.sky-map.org/?ra=0.7132431932282947&de=41.281107146993776&zoom=9&show_grid=1&show_constellation_lines=1&show_constellation_boundaries=1&show_const_names=0&show_galaxies=1&show_box=1&box_ra=24.807611&box_de=37.43182&box_width=14218.912256&box_height=14218.912256&box_var_size=1&img_source=DSS2), and use the data to generate some kind of musical signal.

Of course, there are [higher resolution](http://hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/2015/02/image/a/warn/) images of the Andromeda galaxy (and [*much* higher resolution images](http://petapixel.com/2015/01/07/100-million-stars-looks-like-nasa-releases-1-5-gigapixel-photo-andromeda-galaxy/), but I still thought the site was cool.

Maybe you could have a cursor that navigates the map (or downloaded image) in real-time?

**Solar Wind**

The [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) is a stream of charged particles coming off the Sun. The solar wind isn't very dense (you wouldn't feel it if you were sitting in space), but it does have a lot of effects on Earth.

You can see the solar wind on Earth in the form of the [Auroras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora), or you can get current data on the solar wind speed from a place like [SpaceWeather.com](http://www.spaceweather.com/) which is updated every ten minutes. You can get the same data from [the NOAA](http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/) once a minute.

Archived data from the [ACE satellite](http://www.srl.caltech.edu/ACE/ASC/rtsw.html) is available, but you have to contact them to gain access.

At once a minute, it will be hard to get audio data. However, there are multiple instruments, so you might take the data from each instrument and use that data for several seconds, then switch to the next instrument, etc.

Alternately, you could just download several days worth of data and loop through them in "real-time" if that's acceptable for your project. In this case, you could speed up the data, so you're using one sample per second or something more useful. You wouldn't be able to construct direct sound waves, but you might use the data to change the pitch or tempo of your music.

If you take a lot of data, you can string it together as a sound file, but it would take quite a lot. I remember someone making an audio file of [Comet Shoemaker Levy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9) hitting Jupiter using the pressure differences in the solar wind. Unfortunately I can't find a link to the audio itself. You can hear a similar clip from [Voyager 1](http://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/voyager-sound.html) as it approached the [Heliopause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere) in 2004. In that case, they compressed three hours into six seconds.

**Pulsars**

[Pulsars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar) are cool (in the "really, really hot, but totally awesome" sense of "cool") because they spin really, really fast and emit a cycle of blinking lights. [This](http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/data/access/gbm/) site has stuff about pulsar data, but I haven't quite figured out how to access it. I'm sure you could send an email to them and they (might) help you out.

The really fast ones rotate like 625 times per second (that an *entire star* rotating 625 times per second). Which is both awesome, and useful to you. 250 Hz is about the top end of human speech ranges ([singing gets a lot higher](https://musescore.org/node/4581) -- up to 1000 Hz is normal, and around 25000 Hz is the world record -- most humans can't even hear that high of a pitch).

This means you can pretty much directly match the rotation to the note of an instrument and get some kind of "music" out of it. If you can find a way to get real-time data off one, that is.

**Quasars**

[Quasars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) are enormously powerful black holes that have more cool properties (like putting out a thousand times more power than our entire galaxy), but they're all really far away. Which is good, because we'd probably all be dead if one was remotely close to us. But it means you can't just look up with a simple telescope and see most of them.

That said, [quasar 3C_273](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3C_273) has an apparent brightness of 12.8, meaning larger amateur telescopes can see it. The Wikipedia article says it can be seen in May, so that probably won't help you. Plus you'd have to do it at night.

I can't find any quasars being studied in real-time, though I suppose you could hire someone on the other side of the world to put up a telescope for the duration of your project and stream it across the net.